# how to retain state of the previous state

Tags: reactjs, state, react-context

say I have a button `<Button onClick={updateAndSave()}>`, and a set of State `const [random,setRandom] = useState(randomValue())`

Whenever I click on the button, the `random` gets updated. Say I have done a few lines like this:

```
let h = random;
let y = random + 2;
```

So, whenever `random` changes, all the variables where it has been used gets updated as well. But, What I'd like to be able to do is store the `random`'s value in the previous click as well. How do I do this? I see it not being much possible because, wherever `random` is used it get's updated, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: Need more context. Are you using a class-based component? Are you using a functional component? There are standard ways to access values from previous render cycle for both. Looks like you are using functional components, see the [hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state).

Comment: @DrewReese, yes, I'm using functional components

Comment: Was the link I provided sufficient for your needs in referencing *a* previous value? Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt?

Answer (score 1):

That works as expected. What you can do if you really want to keep the previous states of the clicks is instead of assigning `random` as an integer, use a data structure to keep the states. You can use an array and just append and append each click, or use an object to keep key value pairs `click1: 12`

As array:

```
let random = [];
random.push(randomValue());
random.push(randomValue());
// random = [1,3]

As object:
let random = {};
random.click1 = randomValue();
random.click2 = randomValue();
// random = {click1: 1, click2: 3}
```

Depends on your use case and how you want to retrieve the previous states